Partial dependence plot from scratch - XgBoost depth 1
There are several packages that introduces enhanced explainability to a ML model like XGBoost, for example PiML. And there is a lot of other resources online about different aspects of interpretability, for example partial dependence plots.
https://selfexplainml.github.io/PiML-Toolbox/_build/html/guides/models/xgb1.html
https://medium.com/dataman-in-ai/how-is-the-partial-dependent-plot-computed-8d2001a0e556
I wish to build interpretability from scratch for a XGBoost model with depth 1.
The first step is to, according to the PiMl-link above, is: "calculating the accumulated leaf node values for each bin generated by the unique splits".
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
iris = datasets.load_iris() 
X = iris.data               
y = iris.target 


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

y_train = np.array([0 if i==2 else 1 for i in  y_train])
y_test = np.array([0 if i==2 else 1 for i in  y_test])

train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)

params = {'objective': 'binary:logistic', 
          'eval_metric': 'auc',
          'seed':10,
          'max_depth': 1
         }

model = xgb.train(params, train, num_boost_round=10)


dump = model.get_dump()

The dump object holds information about splits and leaf values. However, I'm struggling to grasp the meaning of 'accumulated leaf values'. If anyone could help me understand this or direct me to recourses I would be very grateful.
